Smarter way to create diff between two pandas dataframes?
I have two pandas dataframes which represent a directory structure with file hashes like
import pandas as pd

dir_old = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file1", "Hash": "hash1"},
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file2", "Hash": "hash2"},
    {"Filepath": "dir2/file3", "Hash": "hash3"},
])

dir_new = pd.DataFrame([
    # {"Filepath": "dir1/file1", "Hash": "hash1"}, # deleted file
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file2", "Hash": "hash2"},
    {"Filepath": "dir2/file3", "Hash": "hash5"},  # changed file
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file4", "Hash": "hash4"},  # new file
])

The dir_new shows the content of the directory structure after some changes. To compare these two dataframes I use
df_merged = pd.merge(dir_new, dir_old, how='outer', indicator=True)
print(df_merged)

This will return
     Filepath   Hash      _merge
0  dir1/file1  hash1  right_only
1  dir1/file2  hash2        both
2  dir1/file4  hash4   left_only
3  dir2/file3  hash3  right_only
4  dir2/file3  hash5   left_only

It is easy to identify the right_only rows as deleted, both as unchanged and  left_only as new files. However what to do about the modified file dir/file3 which appears twice as right_only and left_only? I did the following:
# The indicator columns _merge has categorical values. 
# We need to convert it to string to be able to add later a new value `modified`
df_merged["State"] = df_merged["_merge"].astype(str)
df_merged = df_merged.drop(columns=["_merge"])

# Identify the rows with duplicated filepath and only keep the new (left_only) ones
modified = df_merged[df_merged.duplicated(subset=["Filepath"], keep=False)]
keep = modified[modified["State"] == "left_only"]
drop = modified[modified["State"] == "right_only"]

# Rename the state of the new modified files to `changed` and drop the old duplicated row
df_merged.iloc[keep.index, df_merged.columns.get_loc("State")] = "changed"
df_dropped = df_merged.drop(drop.index)

# Finally rename the State for all the remaining rows
df_final = df_dropped.replace(to_replace=["right_only", "left_only", "both"],
                              value=["deleted", "created", "equal"]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_final) 

The output is
     Filepath   Hash    State
0  dir1/file1  hash1  deleted
1  dir1/file2  hash2    equal
2  dir1/file4  hash4  created
3  dir2/file3  hash5  changed

So it works. But is strikes me as a very complicated solution. Is there maybe a smarter way create a diff between these two dataframes and especially to identify the modified rows between dir_old and dir_new ?

I'd do it first by merging only by Filepath and then compare Hash_x/Hash_y and indicator accordingly (seems straightforward to me):
df = dir_new.merge(dir_old, on="Filepath", how="outer", indicator=True)

hash_changed = df["Hash_x"] != df["Hash_y"]

deleted = df["_merge"] == "right_only"
created = df["_merge"] == "left_only"
changed = (df["_merge"] == "both") & hash_changed
unchanged = (df["_merge"] == "both") & ~hash_changed

df.loc[deleted, "Status"] = "deleted"
df.loc[created, "Status"] = "created"
df.loc[changed, "Status"] = "changed"
df.loc[unchanged, "Status"] = "unchanged"

df["Hash"] = df[["Hash_x", "Hash_y"]].bfill(axis=1)["Hash_x"]

print(df[["Filepath", "Hash", "Status"]])

Prints:
     Filepath   Hash     Status
0  dir1/file1  hash1    deleted
1  dir1/file2  hash2  unchanged
2  dir1/file4  hash4    created
3  dir2/file3  hash5    changed


EDIT: Example of dynamic column names:
df = dir_new.merge(dir_old, on="Filepath", how="outer", indicator=True)
column_names = dir_new.columns.difference(["Filepath"])

hash_changed = df["Hash_x"] != df["Hash_y"]

deleted = df["_merge"] == "right_only"
created = df["_merge"] == "left_only"
changed = (df["_merge"] == "both") & hash_changed
unchanged = (df["_merge"] == "both") & ~hash_changed

df.loc[deleted, "Status"] = "deleted"
df.loc[created, "Status"] = "created"
df.loc[changed, "Status"] = "changed"
df.loc[unchanged, "Status"] = "unchanged"

for c in column_names:
    df[c] = df[[f"{c}_x", f"{c}_y"]].bfill(axis=1)[f"{c}_x"]

print(df[["Filepath", *column_names, "Status"]])


What if I have more columns like "file type", "creation date", "tag", etc.. ? I could add a line with bfill for all of these columns (like you do for Hash), but then my code needs to know the name of all these columns and I might mess up the original order of the columns. Or can this also be done in a smarter way?

@asmaier You can get all columns names from df.columns, and use for-loop to bfill the NaN values (except Filepath and Status of course)

Thank you. I like it. It looks more tidy and clear than my solution.

One can also the new Series.case_when(…) method (pandas 2.2.0 or later). Taking the same approach as @Andrej…
import pandas as pd

dir_old = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file1", "Hash": "hash1"},
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file2", "Hash": "hash2"},
    {"Filepath": "dir2/file3", "Hash": "hash3"},
])

dir_new = pd.DataFrame([
    # {"Filepath": "dir1/file1", "Hash": "hash1"}, # deleted file
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file2", "Hash": "hash2"},
    {"Filepath": "dir2/file3", "Hash": "hash5"},  # changed file
    {"Filepath": "dir1/file4", "Hash": "hash4"},  # new file
])

df_merged = pd.merge(
    dir_new, dir_old, on='Filepath', how='outer', indicator=True
)

print(
    df_merged
    .assign(
        Hash=lambda d: d['Hash_x'].fillna(d['Hash_y']),
        Status=lambda d:  # NA is our fallthrough value (if cases are not exhaustive)
            pd.Series(pd.NA, index=d.index, dtype='string')
            .case_when([
                (d['_merge'] == 'right_only',                          'deleted'  ),
                (d['_merge'] == 'left_only',                           'created'  ),
                (d['_merge'].eq('both') & d['Hash_x'].ne(d['Hash_y']), 'changed'  ),
                (d['_merge'].eq('both') & d['Hash_x'].eq(d['Hash_y']), 'unchanged'),
            ]),
    )
    .drop(columns=['Hash_x', 'Hash_y', '_merge'])
)
#      Filepath   Hash     Status
# 0  dir1/file1  hash1    deleted
# 1  dir1/file2  hash2  unchanged
# 2  dir1/file4  hash4    created
# 3  dir2/file3  hash5    changed


Here are two options:
Option 1 (without .sort_values):
df_m = (pd.merge(dir_old, dir_new, how='outer', indicator='State'))

# get `True` for all duplicates
dupl = df_m['Filepath'].duplicated(keep=False)

# `True for all `right_only`
right_only = df_m['State'].eq('right_only')

# `True` only for duplicates with `right_only`: we will change value here
change = dupl & right_only

# `True` only for duplicates with `right_only`: we will delete value here
delete = dupl & (~right_only)

df_m = (
    df_m
    .assign(State=df_m['State']
            .cat.rename_categories(['deleted', 'created', 'equal'])
            .cat.add_categories('changed')
            .mask(change, 'changed'))
    .loc[~delete]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

Output:
     Filepath   Hash    State
0  dir1/file1  hash1  deleted
1  dir1/file2  hash2    equal
2  dir2/file3  hash5  changed
3  dir1/file4  hash4  created


Option 2 (with .sort_values)
A little easier on the eyes, though slower surely:
df_m = (pd.merge(dir_old, dir_new, how='outer', indicator='State')
        .sort_values('State'))

df_m = (
    df_m
    .assign(State=df_m['State']
            .cat.rename_categories(['deleted', 'created', 'equal'])
            .cat.add_categories('changed')
            .mask(df_m['Filepath'].duplicated(), 'changed'))
    .drop_duplicates(subset='Filepath', keep='last', ignore_index=True)
)

Output:
     Filepath   Hash    State
0  dir1/file1  hash1  deleted
1  dir2/file3  hash5  changed
2  dir1/file4  hash4  created
3  dir1/file2  hash2    equal

Explanation

First, apply pd.merge with implied on=None, getting the intersection of the columns in both dfs, stored as df_m. Instead of indicator=True pass the desired column label, State. Note that I'm using dir_old as the left df, dir_new as the right one.

For the logic in the next steps to work, we need to chain df.sort_values on 'State' (or on ['Filepath', 'State']) to get 'left_only' rows for duplicates before 'right_only' ones. (Unfortunately, pd.merge does not guarantee preservation of input order: for me, it did with pd 2.0.3, it did not with pd 2.2.1.)

This is what we know about 'Filepath' values in df_m:

(default) 'Filepath' value is not a duplicate:

'left_only': 'deleted'
'right_only': 'created'
'both': 'equal'



Let's rename the categories (in this order) accordingly using Series.cat.rename_categories.

'Filepath' value is a duplicate:

'left_only' will be first row (from dir_old): delete it
'right_only' will be second row (from dir_new): change value from 'created' to 'changed'



These operations we can implement by looking at the duplicates.

First, we need to add 'changed' to our categories via Series.cat.add_categories.

Now, we use Series.duplicated for df_m['State'] to mark only the second occurrence of duplicates as True with default keep='first'. The resulting boolean series we use inside Series.mask to change all values where True into 'changed'.

The final series is fed to df.assign(State=...) thus overwriting the original indicator column.

All that's left is to drop from df_m the rows with first duplicates in df_m['Filepath']. Use df.drop_duplicates, passing subset=Filepath and keep='last' this time. Adding ignore_index=True restores a continuous integer index.



With .sort_values(['Filepath', 'State']), df_m will become:
     Filepath   Hash    State
0  dir1/file1  hash1  deleted
1  dir1/file2  hash2    equal
2  dir1/file4  hash4  created
3  dir2/file3  hash5  changed


Oh, that is nice and short. But is it guaranteed, that after the merge the first row of the duplicates will always be from the left dir_old, so your drop_duplicates keep='last' will drop the correct row?

Yeah, valid Q. Was trying to find the definite answer myself, but no luck thus far. I did test numerous combinations to check and it always returned dir_old as first row, and dir_new as second, but I failed to find a doc ref confirming that this always will happen. So, was in fact thinking of adding a Q here on SO to get some input from others. I do know that it will always work if you explicitly sort on State. So, using df_m = pd.merge(dir_old, dir_new, how='outer', indicator='State').sort_values('State'). Of course, you'll lose some performance there, with an extra sort.

Did a bit more digging and unfortunately, order preservation is not guaranteed, so afraid that this method requires the additional .sort_values to be sure. Updated the answer accordingly; hopefully, still of use.

Ok, and an option without the sort :). Let me know if it's unclear how that option differs; used inline comments here for the explanation.
